# How does a Guice-Provider implemented as an identity function work?

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to make sense of the following provider:

```
@Provides
@ScopeMatching
@MatchingScopeAnnotation
MatchingBag provideBag(MatchingBag bag) {
    return bag;
}
```

Here are the declarations of the referenced annotations:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ScopeMatching {
    // nothing
}

@ScopeAnnotation
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
private @interface MatchingScopeAnnotation {
    // nothing
}
```

Looks strange to define a provider that is just an identity function.  I can see that deleting the provider results in injection errors, so it is significant.

Can you please help me understand what the effect of the provider is? Isn't it a chicken-egg problem to resolve the provider? How does Guice do it?

Comment: I'm guessing that there's another provider, or an automatic singleton annotated with one of the two annotations and this function provides that binding's `bag` to the constructors annotated with this function's scope annotation.

Comment: Yes, MatchingBag has an constructor: @Inject MatchingBag(Config config) (we can assume that Guice knows how to construct the Config class). Note that these constructors are not annotated with any scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Guice, a `@ScopeMatching MatchingBag` is a completely different key than an unqualified `MatchingBag`. Stripped away, you can think of it as analogous to `@Provides A provideA(AImpl impl) { return impl; }`.

Guice acts like a `Map<Key, Provider>` where a Key is a qualified type with an optional binding annotation. You have a custom binding annotation here, `ScopeMatching`, with the appropriate meta-annotation `@BindingAnnotation`. Consequently, with the binding you're asking about, both keys (unqualified `MatchingBag` and `@ScopeMatching MatchingBag`) are available through your object graph, where the former always returns a new instance and the latter returns an instance in the `MatchingScopeAnnotation` scope (which may be a new instance and may be a saved/cached instance according to your Scope implementation).

Your "identity" binding is equivalent to the possibly-more-recognizable `bind` version:

```
bind(MatchingBag.class).annotatedWith(ScopeMatching.class)
    .to(MatchingBag.class)
    .in(MatchingScopeAnnotation.class);
```

...or equivalently, and even clearer:

```
bind(Key.get(MatchingBag.class, ScopeMatching.class))
    .to(Key.get(MatchingBag.class))
    .in(MatchingScopeAnnotation.class);
```

See more in the [Guice docs on Binding Annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations).